# G-d can help and cast down

Tags: book-of-chronicles

In [*Divrei HaYamim* (II 25:8)](http://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.25.8?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) it says, *"... for G-d has the power to help and to cast down."*

Why is *Divrei HaYamim* telling us something so obvious?

Comment: Did you look at the context?

Comment: In Tehillim 145 it says גדול יי God is great. Why does it say something so obvious?

Answer (score 1):

As Rashi ([ibid](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01463.html#HtmpReportNum0025_L2)) explains:

> **לעזור ולהכשיל.** פתרון יש לו כח וגבורה לעזור לך בלא חיל של אפרים ולהכשיל אותך אם תוליכם עמך

The *Man of Gcd* - mentioned in the previous verse - is warning King אֲמַצְיָהוּ that he should not add 100,000 soldiers from Ephraim to his army, for **Gcd has the ability to help** him win the war without them, and **Gcd has the ability to cast him down** and make him lose the war even if he takes along these unwanted reinforcements.